# java AbstractTableModel 2 Different Color For Each Row

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I want to increase readability  of my jtable , here is  MyTableModel.java class below , how to make each row with 2 different color  [shown in this picture](http://www.microsoft.com/library/media/1033/athome/images/tiptalk/table.jpg) . What should be the  specific method  that I can give different color to each row to increase readability of the user.

```
      public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

   String [] columnNames;
   Vector<Vector<Object>> data;
   public DataAccessObject  ObjDb = new DataAccessObject ();


   public  MyTableModel(String [] coln , Vector<Vector<Object>>  data)
   {

       columnNames = coln;
       this.data =data;

   }

   @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

   @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

   @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data.get(row).get(col);
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }


        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {

            if (col <= 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data.get(row).set(col, value);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }




      private class RowListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                return;
            }
//            output.append("ROW SELECTION EVENT. ");
//            outputSelection();
        }
    }

    private class ColumnListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                return;
            }
//            output.append("COLUMN SELECTION EVENT. ");
//            outputSelection();
        }
    }

}
```

Netbeans automatically created my jtable with variable name I set is mytable  then I 
   have problem with defining  prepareRenderer below , do I miss step here ? I wanna make
   each row with different color Here is my sample code below.

```
       mytable.prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            //  Alternate row color

            if (!isRowSelected(row))
                c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? getBackground() : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            return c;
        }
    };
```

I have also use this one but this sets 5 columns i have 7 columns remaining two is not
colored at the end , when I click the white colored row the text color disappears.

```
 mytable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer() {
    private DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean      
  isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,             


isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);


        System.out.println(column);

        if (row % 2 == 0) {
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
        return c;
    }

});
```

Comment: `What should be the specific - Oracle tutorial` - [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Your second example won't work because that's now how you override methods and your third method has problems when the class type is not `Object` and it has a pre-defined renderer for those column types...hence the reason I'm not a fan of those methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You could...

Use `JXTable` from [SwingLabs, SwingX library](https://java.net/projects/swingx) which has functionality which could do this...this would be my preferred solution if you can use 3rd party libraries...

### You could...

Use Nimbus look and feel which does this...but this precludes you from using other look and feels (like the system look and feel)

### You could...

Create your own series of custom `TableCellRenderer`s which color their background based on the current row...this is tedious as EVERY cell renderer you might need, needs to be able to perform this operation...

### You could...

Override the `prepareCellRenderer` method of the `JTable` and forcefully set the background of the cell renderer yourself, based on the row...I'm not a fan of this solution, as it's forcing a design choice onto the renderer which might not fit it's requirements (overriding values the cell renderer might want) and locks you into a particular implementation of the table...

### You could...

Create a `JViewport` which was capable of talking with the `JTable` and rendered the candy stripping underneath the table, but the table and renderers would need to be transparent...I've done this, it's...complicated...but allowed me to continue the candy stripping the full length of the view port (beyond the renderable area of the table)...

**Updated with `JViewport` example**

This is an example of a concept I implemented a while ago for a project (it is actually managed by an `interface` so I could include `JList` and `JTextArea` as well, but that's another question)...

Basically, it makes the `JViewport`, which appears below the `JTable`, responsible for rendering the actual candy stripping.

But "why?" you ask...because it doesn't affect the table or cell renderer.  The only requirement that this makes is that both the table and cell renderers are transparent (unless they have to be otherwise).

This means, you don't need to put candy stripping logic in your renderers, this means you don't need to override `prepareRenderer` of every table you create and mangle the requirements of the cell renderers...

It's far from perfect, but demonstrates the basic idea...

[image: CandyStripped]

Okay, but why bother?  Well, basically, this approach allows you to paint beyond the area painted by the table...

[image: CandyStripping]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CandyStrippedTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CandyStrippedTable();
    }

    public CandyStrippedTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Object[] columns = new Object[10];
                for (int col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
                    columns[col] = (char) (65 + col);
                }

                Object[][] data = new Object[10][10];
                for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
                        data[row][col] = row + "x" + col;
                    }
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

                    @Override
                    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                        setOpaque(isSelected);
                        return this;
                    }
                    
                });
                table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                table.setOpaque(false);

                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
                sp.setViewport(new CandyStrippedViewPort(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128)));
                sp.setViewportView(table);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(sp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CandyStrippedViewPort extends JViewport {

        private Color candyStrippedColor;

        public CandyStrippedViewPort(Color color) {
            candyStrippedColor = color;
        }

        public Color getCandyStrippedColor() {
            return candyStrippedColor;
        }

        public void setCandyStrippedColor(Color candyStrippedColor) {
            this.candyStrippedColor = candyStrippedColor;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getCandyStrippedColor());
            Component view = getView();
            if (view instanceof JTable) {
                JTable table = (JTable) view;
                Rectangle viewRect = getViewRect();
                int y = 0;
                int row = 0;
                if (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    row = table.rowAtPoint(viewRect.getLocation());
                    while (row < table.getRowCount()) {
                        int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight(row);
                        Rectangle cellRect = table.getCellRect(row, 0, true);
                        if (row % 2 == 0) {
                            g2d.fillRect(0, cellRect.y - viewRect.y, getWidth(), cellRect.height);
                        }
                        y = cellRect.y + cellRect.height;
                        row++;
                    }
                }
                int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight();
                while (y < getHeight()) {
                    if (row % 2 == 0) {
                        g2d.fillRect(0, y, getWidth(), rowHeight);
                    }
                    row++;
                    y += rowHeight;
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Formatting numbers in cell renderers**

You could start with something like...

```
obj.table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, 
    new DefaultTableCellRenderer() { 
        @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) { 
            if (value instanceof Number) {
                value = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(value);
            }
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
            setOpaque(isSelected); 
            return this; 
        } 
    });
```

If, for some reason, the default format instead suitable, you could do something like...

```
obj.table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, 
    new DefaultTableCellRenderer() { 
        @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) { 
            if (value instanceof Number) {
                NumberFormat ni = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                ni.setMaximumFractionDigits(2)
                value = ni.format(value);
            }
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
            setOpaque(isSelected); 
            return this; 
        } 
    });
```

Instead

Comment: how about the first one mytable.prepareRenderer what is the problem with that ?

Comment: You not overriding the method, you're calling it...You can't override a method from an instance of a object...If you have a look at my example, I'm overriding the `getTableCellRendererComponent` of the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` inline

Comment: this overriding issue always confusing  me , what do you think i have to look at to understand this and in your example , you have added your table jframe , but you know netbeans creates everything automatically , integration is complicated for me always. will I  pass my table and its model to candy class ? is that enough ?

Comment: You need to set the `JScrollPane` viewport, but your will need set the `JTable` as the viewports view, as it done in the example...might want to put the form editor away for a while, it won't help you with this kind of work

Comment: ok i did , but you know my last column is not affected with your code why ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tIFybzjEhednVib3hKYWs1RTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Probably because the cell renderer which is been used to render the value is opaque.  What type of data is it

Comment: You need to replace the `Number` renderer with one of your own.  Use the class type of `Number.class`.  PS- You can also set the viewport background color to white ;)

Comment: it is big integer what to do now,  can you update your code , i couldn't get you !

Comment: this is the field i added to my table model   public Class [] colTypes = { String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class , String.class , Number.class };

Comment: and this one   @Override
       public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return colTypes[columnIndex];
    }

Comment: ok i have done finally i just dublicated the  mytable.setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() and make it Number.Class https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tIFybzjEheOWpFV2xYTUc4bUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: engineer , I have added new currency renderes and and editor to my last column , i am having the same issue last column is not editable and your candy is not effected         obj.jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(BigDecimal.class, new CurrencyRenderer(nf));
        obj.jTable1.setDefaultEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CurrencyEditor(nf));

Comment: Cell editiability to defined by two things. 1- the result of the call to `TableModel#isCellEditable` and 2- the result of the call to `TableCellEditor#isCellEdtiable`, when these both return `true`, then the cell will be editable.  The candy stripping problem is because your `CurrencyRenderer` is always opaque, when it only needs to be opaque when selected.

Comment: @madengineer here is my code with candy and currencyrenderer what to add or remove here https://www.dropbox.com/s/hij9127d1v6eoo3/Candy%20With%20Currency%20Renderer.txt

Comment: You need to override the `getTableCellRendererComponent` in the `CurrencyRenderer` and `setOpaque` to true ONLY when the cell is selected, just like I did when setting the default renderer for the `Object.class`

Comment: yeah I did thanks thanks mad programmer , i am warming up with this things sorry for too many questions !   obj.jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(BigDecimal.class, new CurrencyRenderer(nf) {
        
         @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                setOpaque(isSelected);
                return this;
            }
            });

Comment: hello mad engineer ,in your candy strip model  how to set double values with MinimumFractionDigits(1) like in JSpinners  where to add code for it which type of code to add.

Comment: That's the responsibility of the editors and renderers.  You can use a `NumberFormat` if the underlying data is in a numerical format

Comment: should add whithin  this        obj.table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                setOpaque(isSelected);
                return this;
            }

        });

Comment: I am so confused , can you please update your answer with double fraction minimum , I tried to add this if (value instanceof Number){
Locale myLocale = Locale.getDefault(); NumberFormat numberFormatB = NumberFormat.getInstance(myLocale) numberFormatB.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
editor.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
             new NumberFormatter(numberFormatB)));
       editor.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        editor.setValue(value);
    } but not functioning

Answer (score 2):

See this [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) made by Camick. It'll solve your problem.

You can use his method `createAlternating` for rendering the colors of the row.

```
  private JComponent createAlternating(DefaultTableModel model)
  {
    JTable table = new JTable( model )
    {
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            //  Alternate row color

            if (!isRowSelected(row))
                c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? getBackground() : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            return c;
        }
    };

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
    return new JScrollPane( table );
}
```

Comment: See better :) - I just don't like that approach, but that's just me ;)

Comment: but i already have abstractablemodel how to integrate this to my code

Comment: @okrman, this solution has nothing to do with your TableModel. The integration is with the JTable. Did you read the link and download the example working code?

Comment: yeah i understood that is about table rendering  things , see  my question again i have updated it !

Answer (score 1):

long time ago, i had the same problem.

In this case i use the JXTable from the swingX library instead of the JTable.
This componenet has a great method:

```
addHighlighter(HighlighterFactory.createSimpleStriping());
```

good luck