# Issue with code blocking EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, event-dispatch-thread

I have a JTable. In it, I override the prepareRenderer function. I profiled my application, and got the following results:

[image]

(Sorry, that might be to small to read). It is the first line. The point is, I am spending a ton of time in that function and it is blocking my UI. Significantly more time than any other function of the whole application as you can see by the bar graph. I am not quite sure how I can get my code off of the EDT.

All it is really doing is determining what color to paint the component. I wouldn't think this is time consuming. This leads me to believe that it is the number of times it is being called. I could be wrong on that.

I know of `SwingWorker`, but my problem revolves around the fact that I am under them impression most of this function should be on the EDT.

Can anyone assist me in getting this function to stop blocking?

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    Color alternateColor = ColorRepository.Table.ALTERNATE_ROW_COLOR;
    Color lightGray = ColorRepository.Table.ROW_COLOR;
    if (!returnComp.getBackground().equals(getSelectionBackground())) {
        if (columnColors.containsKey(column) && requiredColumn.containsKey(column) == false) {
            returnComp.setBackground(columnColors.get(column));
        } else if (requiredColumn.containsKey(column) && getValueAt(row, column) == null) {
            returnComp.setBackground(requiredColumn.get(column));
        } else if (shouldModifyColumn.containsKey(column) && getValueAt(row, column).equals(shouldModifyColumn.get(column))) {
            returnComp.setBackground(shouldModifyColumnColor.get(column));
        } else {
            Color bg = (row % 2 == 0 ? alternateColor : lightGray);
            returnComp.setBackground(bg);
        }
    }

    if (!returnComp.getForeground().equals(getSelectionForeground())) {
        if (canModifyColumnColors.containsKey(column) && returnComp instanceof DefaultTableCellRenderer) {
            returnComp.setForeground(canModifyColumnColors.get(column));
        } else {
            returnComp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    if (moneyColumn.containsKey(column) && returnComp instanceof DefaultTableCellRenderer) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) renderer;
        cellRenderer.setText(Formatter.setDigitsOfPerceision(cellRenderer.getText(), moneyColumn.get(column)));
    }

    if (percentColumn.containsKey(column) && returnComp instanceof DefaultTableCellRenderer) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) renderer;
        cellRenderer.setText(Formatter.setDigitsOfPerceision(cellRenderer.getText(), percentColumn.get(column)));
    }

    if (toolTip.containsKey(column) && returnComp instanceof JComponent) {
        ((JComponent) returnComp).setToolTipText(toolTip.get(column));
    }

    return returnComp;
}
```

Comment: Overriding `preapreRenderer` is a real poor approach to what is already a flexible API.  Instead, define a custom `TableCellRenderer`s for your needs and apply it to the appropriate column or column class type.

Comment: `prepareRenderer` will be called for EACH and EVERY cell, so it's not unreasonable for it to be called a large number of times, especially when the table is updated, as it may need to make calculations in order to update it's own state

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good idea. I inherited this code and was going along with what was already being done. I will give that a shot and see if it improves performance.

Comment: You can't get it off the EDT. What you can do is figure out why it's slow, and make it faster.

Comment: I don't have a problem with setting the background color in this method so the logic is not built into every renderer, but formatting the text should be left up to each renderer.

Comment: Candy stripping can be achieve in a number of different ways, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279727/java-abstracttablemodel-2-different-color-for-each-row/25279954#25279954).  I prefer to remove the requirements for the candy stripping away from the cell renderers and into it's own domain, this makes it much easier to develop cell renderers without needing to worry about adding in additional functionality or extending from some base renderer which might not entirely meet the needs of the renderer

Comment: @camickr It can get messy and complicated, as the color of the cell might need to be set by the renderer itself, which you've now just gone and changed as an example (this happens to us all the time, hence the reason I don't like it ;)) - But I'd also prefer to be use a `JXTable`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I guess that is something I've never thought of. Typically when you want row level rendering to be a consistent background you would use foreground color colors to differentiate cell values (+ve and -ve numbers, for example). This approach is not suggested for cell level backgrounds.

Comment: @camickr Oh my boss is such an "awesome" UI designer :P