# Can we use prepareRenderer component and custom cell Renderer together?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to use prepareRenderer component with custom cell renderer. The idea is to paint entire row using prepareRenderer and cell value based customisations using customer cell renderer.

prepareRenderer works as expected by highlighting the entire row but cell highlighted by custom cell renderer do not display colour unless selected. Custom cell rendering only seems to be working upon cell selection (highlighting cell containing 1 but only upon selection).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGGvc.png]

Any ideas on how to make both work hand in hand?

Code below to reproduce the issue.

```
[![import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class SortTableWithColors_ extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        SortTableWithColors_ frame = new SortTableWithColors_();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SortTableWithColors_() {
        Object\[\] columnNames = {"B", "C"};
        Object\[\]\[\] data = {{new Integer(1), new Integer(4)},
                {new Integer(2), new Integer(5)},
                {new Integer(3), new Integer(3)},
                {new Integer(4), new Integer(1)}};
        // table model
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        // set table model in Jtable
//        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        NewJTable table = new NewJTable(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));

        // Tell the table what to use to render our columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new NewRenderer());
        }
    }

    // Custom Renderer
    public class NewRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
                (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                 boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JLabel cell = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent
                    (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            int rowModel = (int) table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            int colModel = (int) table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
            int rowView = (int) table.convertRowIndexToView(row);
            int colView = (int) table.convertColumnIndexToView(column);

            // set color
//            cell.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
//            cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000));

            //set selection colors
            if (isSelected) {
                cell.setBackground(new Color(0x4AC3FF));
                cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000)); // AM
            }
            // Selective cell colouring based on value

            // paint cells
            int val = (int) value;
            if (val == 1) {
                cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }

    public class NewJTable extends JTable {
        public NewJTable(TableModel model) {
            super(model);
        }

        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            //  Color row based on a cell value
            if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                c.setBackground(getBackground());
                int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                int val = (int) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
                if (val == 3) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            }
            return c;

        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: In theory, yes, but you'll probably find that you are constantly having to make modifications as the `prepareRenderer` changes what the `TableCellRenderer` wanted based on the data it has

Comment: For a nice little rant on the subject, you could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279727/java-abstracttablemodel-2-different-color-for-each-row/25279954#25279954), it's not a "perfect" solution, but it's step in a better direction, with some neat side effects ;)

Comment: That's helpful and a lot of food for thought. I like the idea of using Jviewport for rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do two things at once. You need to break the rendering down logically into two steps.

The renderer code is executed before the prepare renderer code. So:

1. Frst you need to get the renderer working the way you want it to work.
2. Then secondly you override the default rendering by highlighting the line containing the value 3.

The key point when changing the background in your renderer is that you must always reset it to the default value before doing any customization.

So in the rendering code you need your commented out lines:

```
// set color (ie. restore the default values)
cell.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000));
```

Then in the prepareRenderer you don't need to reset the background, only change it when your condition is met:

```
// get rid of this, the default has already been set. 
// this code should only provide the override
//c.setBackground(getBackground());
```

Note: this will only work if you have a custom renderer on all the columns that resets the background to the default. Because we need to comment out the above statement, it is now the responsibility of each renderer to reset the background.

Comment: @amit, did this not answer your question?

Comment: @ camickr. Yes it did. Sorry for delayed response. I implemented Jviewport route as suggested by MadProgrammer. But do agree with your helpful comments.